# Weird issue in SELECT query in ACCESS DB 2013

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am trying to fetch data from the table based on TransactionDAte beteween two.  Entries are already in the table. But still I am not getting expected Results.

**Invenory Daily Facts Table**

```
ID  PartNumber  Quantity    PalletNo    InvoiceNo   TransactionDate IsAdd IsRestore
23  F005.V01.639-24V    250 1111                      3/16/2016 Yes No
24  F005.V01.639-24V    120 2222                      3/16/2016 Yes No
25  F005.V01.639-24V    170 1111          3333        3/16/2016 No  Yes

SELECT TransactionDate,PartNumber,IsAdd, SUM(Quantity) AS Qty FROM InventoryDailyFacts 
WHERE TransactionDate Between Format(#16/03/2016#,'dd/mm/yyyy') And Format(#16/03/2016#,'dd/mm/yyyy')  
GROUP BY TransactionDate, PartNumber,IsAdd 
ORDER BY TransactionDate desc
```

Zero rows affected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a typical Access weirdness indeed.
Although it is valid SQL and working on other RDBMS, in Access BETWEEN/AND  doesnt work if you define the same dates

If you really want the range on same dates, add the time  :

```
SELECT TransactionDate,PartNumber,IsAdd, SUM(Quantity) AS Qty FROM InventoryDailyFacts 
WHERE TransactionDate Between format(#16/03/2016 00:00:00#, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss') AND format(#16/03/2016 23:59:59#, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss')
GROUP BY TransactionDate, PartNumber,IsAdd 
ORDER BY TransactionDate desc
```

Comment: Is your field type a date or datetime?, I have supposed the latter

Comment: Good catch.... i am so Stupid..... type was short text.. Woahhhhh amazing...................

Answer (score 1):

You must either format the date expressions properly or, as you have the value, use it directly:

```
SELECT TransactionDate,PartNumber,IsAdd, SUM(Quantity) AS Qty 
FROM InventoryDailyFacts 
WHERE TransactionDate Between #03/16/2016# And #03/16/2016#  
GROUP BY TransactionDate, PartNumber,IsAdd 
ORDER BY TransactionDate desc
```

or simply:

```
SELECT TransactionDate, PartNumber, IsAdd, SUM(Quantity) AS Qty 
FROM InventoryDailyFacts 
WHERE TransactionDate = Date()
GROUP BY TransactionDate, PartNumber, IsAdd 
ORDER BY TransactionDate desc
```

or, if *TransactionDate* may have a time part:

```
SELECT TransactionDate, PartNumber, IsAdd, SUM(Quantity) AS Qty 
FROM InventoryDailyFacts 
WHERE Fix(TransactionDate) = Date()
GROUP BY TransactionDate, PartNumber, IsAdd 
ORDER BY TransactionDate desc
```

or, if *TransactionDate* is text, not data type Date:

```
SELECT TransactionDate, PartNumber, IsAdd, SUM(Quantity) AS Qty 
FROM InventoryDailyFacts 
WHERE DateValue(TransactionDate) = Date()
GROUP BY TransactionDate, PartNumber, IsAdd 
ORDER BY TransactionDate desc
```

Comment: The first one doesnt work for me either. I tried  with 4 diffrent formats, and much more, and I also tried like this  `WHERE thedatefield >= fixeddate AND  thedatefield <= fixeddate` It doesnt work if `fixeddate` is exactly the same, it works fine if they are different. Go figure

Comment: It will work if your date field was of data type _Date_, not _Text_. Or if you converted the text to date values. See edit.

Comment: Nope. I *obviously* made all my tests on a date field.

Comment: @ThomasG: Sorry, I took you as the questioneer who used text. However, the first _will_ work because Between .. And is inclusive. If it doesn't, it is because the field has a time part - and if so, neither the second will return records.